# Увеличение раздела внутри раздела ubuntu server 20.04

Tags: ubuntu

Установил на виртуальную машину ubuntu server 20.04. Выделил статический VDI на 1,5 ТБ. Система установилась и по выводу команды **df -h** я увидел, что доступно всего лишь 100 ГБ.

```
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                               1,9G     0  1,9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                              394M  1,4M  392M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv   98G   85G  8,3G  92% /
tmpfs                              2,0G     0  2,0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5,0M     0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                              2,0G     0  2,0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0                          62M   62M     0 100% /snap/core20/1376
/dev/loop1                          62M   62M     0 100% /snap/core20/1361
/dev/loop2                          68M   68M     0 100% /snap/lxd/22526
/dev/loop3                          44M   44M     0 100% /snap/snapd/14978
/dev/loop4                          68M   68M     0 100% /snap/lxd/21835
/dev/sda2                          1,5G  209M  1,2G  16% /boot
tmpfs                              394M     0  394M   0% /run/user/1000
```

Пошел дальше, в **lsblk**, и увидел, что внутри раздела /dev/sda3, размером 1,5 ТБ, создан раздел ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv, размером 100 ГБ.

```
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0                       7:0    0 61,9M  1 loop /snap/core20/1376
loop1                       7:1    0 61,9M  1 loop /snap/core20/1361
loop2                       7:2    0 67,9M  1 loop /snap/lxd/22526
loop3                       7:3    0 43,6M  1 loop /snap/snapd/14978
loop4                       7:4    0 67,2M  1 loop /snap/lxd/21835
sda                         8:0    0  1,5T  0 disk 
├─sda1                      8:1    0    1M  0 part 
├─sda2                      8:2    0  1,5G  0 part /boot
└─sda3                      8:3    0  1,5T  0 part 
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0  100G  0 lvm  /
sr0                        11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
```

В связи с чем возникает несколько вопросов.

1. Как внутри раздела мог создаться ещё один раздел? Где об этом почитать?
2. Надо увеличить размер раздела ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv до нужных мне 1,5 ТБ. Как я могу это сделать?

Comment: «Где об этом почитать?» — ключевое слово для гуглинга: LVM. Если вы не знаете, что это такое, то, вероятно, стоит отключить LVM в процессе установки (он там включен по умолчанию — меня это тоже жутко бесит)

Answer (score 2):

Большое спасибо andreymal за наводку. Действительно, система установилась на логический диск. Решить проблему мне помогла эта статья: https://www.sim-networks.com/ru/wiki/add-disk-space-linux-server-lvm-debian.
Я выполнил следующие команды:

```
sudo lvdisplay - чтобы узнать путь до логического диска (строка LV Path)
sudo vgdisplay - чтобы узнать количество свободного пространства в логической группе (строка Free  PE)
sudo lvextend -l +368370 /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv - расширение логического диска
sudo resize2fs /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv - расширение файловой системы на весь логический диск
```